# ImportError: cannot import name choice when importing sklearn.mixture

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-import

I am using scikit learn 0.15.0. When I try to import sklearn.mixture I get
ImportError: cannot import name choice

Any ideas?

===================================================================

```
In [1]: **from sklearn import mixture**

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-05bc76cab98d> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn import mixture

/home/f/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/mixture/__init__.py in <module>()
      3 """
      4
----> 5 from .gmm import sample_gaussian, log_multivariate_normal_density
      6 from .gmm import GMM, distribute_covar_matrix_to_match_covariance_type
      7 from .gmm import _validate_covars

/home/f/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/mixture/gmm.py in <module>()
     16 from ..utils import check_random_state, deprecated
     17 from ..utils.extmath import logsumexp, pinvh
---> 18 from .. import cluster
     19
     20 from sklearn.externals.six.moves import zip

/home/f/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 """
      5
----> 6 from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
      7 from .mean_shift_ import mean_shift, MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth, \
      8     get_bin_seeds

/home/f/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py in <module>()
     16 from ..neighbors import kneighbors_graph
     17 from ..manifold import spectral_embedding
---> 18 from .k_means_ import k_means
     19
     20

/home/f/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py in <module>()
     28 from ..utils import as_float_array
     29 from ..utils import gen_batches
---> 30 from ..utils.random import choice
     31 from ..externals.joblib import Parallel
     32 from ..externals.joblib import delayed

ImportError: cannot import name choice
```

Comment: Not enough information. How did you install, was it an upgrade, did you try uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: I am using the anaconda package locally installed under my home directory since I have to work around not having admin rights. The machine is running Red Hat 4.4.5-6. I upgraded scikit-learn to 0.15 after installing anaconda.

Comment: Did you try uninstall + reinstall?

Comment: `random.choice` didn't exist before version 0.15, so it's likely an upgrade problem.

Answer (score 8):

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
```

using this would make it more specific to work with .gmm,

and

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

for:

```
     16 from ..neighbors import kneighbors_graph
     17 from ..manifold import spectral_embedding
---> 18 from .k_means_ import k_means
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted, it might have to do with old files (that are implemented in python as opposed to libraries?) in a new package you probably updated using pip install -U packagename (in my case pip install -U scikit-learn) It might be worth first trying to uninstall the package and install it again before manually deleting stuff... (worked in my case)
uninstall
(in my case run it on Anaconda Command prompt):

```
   pip uninstall scikit-learn
```

then:

```
   pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

(added dependencies just in case)
then just to be sure

```
   pip install scikit-learn
```

should say it's installed

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error when I tried to `import KMeans` as : `from sklearn.cluster import KMeans`

`Error > ImportError: cannot import name choice`

I found the answer here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3461

Since I have upgraded to Scikit version 0.15 a few days back, the **older version of** **random.so was present in** `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils`.

I manually deleted it and now I do not get the error anymore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was indeed the problem thanks skv. Since I am using anaconda installed in my home dir, my location was:
 ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/random.so

Answer (score 0):

New implementation is

```
from sklearn import mixture
model = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type='full')
```

Just replace the first two lines

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).