# scikit-learn 0.15.2 Python 3.4 Windows cannot import cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have installed scikit-learn 0.15.2 for Python 3.4 in Windows (8.1) using the MS windows installer:

```
https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/s/scikit-learn/scikit-learn-0.15.2.win-amd64-py3.4.exe
```

The installation seems to work correctly. I am able to import sklearn and some packages without any problems. However, I cannot execute:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

The import fails with the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'choice'

I have unistalled scikit-learn (using Windows uninstall) and installed the pckage again with the same problem. Any suggestions about how to fix it?

Comment: Does the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001270/importerror-cannot-import-name-choice-when-importing-sklearn-mixture) solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Bren. Yes it fixed my problem. I Went into the sklearn/utils and there was a random.pyd file that was old. I removed it and it seems to be working. Anyway, it must be a bug in the upgrade procedure for scikit-learn